# How to setup an IPv6 only network for iOS app testing?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, ipv6, appstore-approval

The first time I got to read about the mandatory support for IPv6 only networks in all new apps to be released in the AppStore was yesterday, when my app got rejected with Apple stating this as the reason.

So, I have been trying to reproduce this from my end. I have gone through the [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1) for the same and have setup a NAT64 network and connected my iPhone to it ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtrGU.png)).

But, when I get over to **test-ipv6.com** or any other websites to check IPv6 connectivity on the device, it shows "**No IPv6 address detected**" message. Also, I am unable to load **ipv6.google.com** which reportedly loads up only on IPv6 networks (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Am I missing something, or is there anything else I can do to test my app for IPv6 only network compatibility?

**P.S:** My app worked and the pages loaded up fine when I tried in this NAT64 network. But, in the Apple's rejection reply, those APIs ended up failing.

Comment: [You're not meant to see a global IPv6 address](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39862158/1068283) when you visit an IPv6 test page from this network. You only see an IPv4 address. Only the local network segment between the iOS device and the Mac running the NAT64 network uses IPv6 in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using AFNetworking?
If yes, update your classes.
Change the following line in code in AFNetworking Library in Class AFNetworkReachabilityManager

CHANGE AF_INET TO AF_INET6;

```
+ (instancetype)sharedManager {
    static AFNetworkReachabilityManager *_sharedManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        struct sockaddr_in address;
        bzero(&address, sizeof(address));
        address.sin_len = sizeof(address);
        address.sin_family = AF_INET6;  //Change AF_INET TO AF_INET6
        _sharedManager = [self managerForAddress:&address];
    });

    return _sharedManager;
}
```

Otherwise, what classes or library are you using for networking?

Edit: As you requested, here is a tutorial on how to test your app and check if it is ipv6 ready:

http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-test-your-app-for-ipv6-compatibility/

[Alternate link over Waybackmachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20180207202735/http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-test-your-app-for-ipv6-compatibility/)

It covers the creation of an  IPv6 NAT64  only network in your mac then sharing internet connection from your mac to your other wifi (or bluetooth or whatever) devices.

Then you can make all the tests within your app, being sure that all calls are made via an ipv6 only network.

**Edit2:**

Those website WON'T BE ABLE to see your ipv6 ip adress. If you used that tutorial, the ipv6 adress is a **private** (internal to your network) adress. It is used to communicate between your iPhone and your mac.
What internet websites see is your **PUBLIC** ip, which is given to your modem by your internet service provider, and which is generally an ipv4 network.

So to conclude: your app is working with its ipv6 adress. Those test websites won't detect it because they only see the public adress of your router / modem.

Please refer to [This link](https://www.iplocation.net/public-vs-private-ip-address) to read more about public vs private ip addresses.

Comment: Yes, I am using AFNetworking, and I have updated my AFNetworking to 3.1 from 2 (which has updates to this class and function providing support for IPv6). This might have solved the problem (and I'm yet to submit a build with this change to AppStore).

My question was actually about testing my app on an IPv6 network on iPhone.

Comment: Well. I will update the answer with a tutorial on how to test the app on an ipv6 network. + don't worry, I faced this issue myself and updating AFNetworking allowed the app to be approved :)

Comment: Sorry buddy! This is the same tutorial which I followed as mentioned in my question.

Going to any of the IPv6 testing website will yield the same result: **"No IPv6 address detected"**

Comment: The ip adress that you will see in those website is your public ip, which is your modem / router ip, and is not your iPhone's IP. This is because you use the modem / router (or your mac if you are using internet sharing) as an intermediate to connect to the internet. So, ipv6 is working in your device to connect to your mac. But those websites WON'T see this ip. it is something internatl. They will only see the public ip (which is usually an ipv4). Please refer to my second edit in my answer

Comment: So actually the setup suggested by Apple doesn't come of use to test this case?

Comment: No, it is useful. If your network is ipv6 ONLY and your app can connect to the network (and via it, to the internet), then you are SURE that it supports ipv6. But in the guide it is never said that your Public ip must be seen by test websites as an ipv6 adress to confirm that the app is working.

Comment: Please refer to figure Figure 10-6 in the guide. I can't post it here due to the NDA. It explains how your ipv6 only network is shared between your mac and your internal devices, but the external network is STILL an ipv4 and sees you as an ipv4

Comment: Hmmm.. Sounds logical... But still it worked in our network, but didn't work for Apple.

Comment: Did they reject it AGAIN?

Comment: Yes. AGAIN. :/

They have rejected it again saying that the app was not getting forward after the login screen in iPad (10.0.2) running on an IPv6 network. I tried simulating this issue in an iPad (10.0.2) running on the network that Apple suggested to test our apps in (Internet sharing from MacBook with NAT64 enabled).

I had submitted the app this time after updating to the latest AFNetworking.

Comment: Oh sorry to hear that. Hope it will work this time. Please note that sometimes the reason is completely different. For example : getting an app rejected for being not able to make IAP on an ipv6 only network, with the same error message as yours, but the real reason is that the In App Purchase ID is wrong. Let's wait and hope it works

Comment: It seems to be something else that was causing the problem. It's not AFNetworking. Accepting your answer since it points to the official setup on the same.

Comment: I see. Did you find the issue? Was your app approved?

Comment: hello, I am facing the same thing. Please if you still remember the solution. I will be so grateful if you will post the solution.

Comment: @RonaldBridger, seriously, you do not write what was the real issue & solution??

Comment: @RonaldBridger I too have the same issue. Please help us.